# Chrome devtools lighthouse not working, serviceworker

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, service-worker, audit, lighthouse

I got Chrome auto updated and now I have the lighthouse tab in devtools instead of the audit.
I used to be able to test my own page via audit and get full score: https://medda86.com/
But now the devtools lighthouse crashes and I think it's because of my serviceworker or something.

It used to run fine before Chrome update, not sure what else it could be.
Please have a go at it if you want and try to find out what it is,
I can't pinpoint exactly what it is.

The service worker should be working, just install, cache, delete old cache, and fetch latest data.
But could be something that have changed.

Chrome version:
Chrome is up to date
Version 95.0.4638.54 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Here is my service worker:

```js
var cacheName = 'site-cache-v1';

// Install
self.addEventListener('install', function(event) {
  event.waitUntil(
    caches.open(cacheName).then(function(cache) {
      //console.log('Service Worker Installed');
    })
  );  
});

// Delete old cache objects
self.addEventListener('activate', function(event) {  
  event.waitUntil(caches.keys().then(function (keyList) {
    Promise.all(keyList.map(function (key) {
      if (key === cacheName) {
        return;
      }
      caches.delete(key);
      //console.log('Old Service Worker '+key+' Deleted');
    }));
  }));
  //console.log('Service Worker Activated');
});

self.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {
  //console.log('Fetch', event.request);
});
```

Comment: Try new update 95.0.4638.69 lighthouse updated on last version https://developer.chrome.com/blog/new-in-devtools-95/#lighthouse

Comment: Are you still seeing this issue? I am having an error on registration after lighthouse times out.

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue, it's google. https://github.com/GoogleChrome/lighthouse/issues/13236

It's the chrome version that makes the lighthouse tab not working. This chrome version has some other issues as well.